# tkinter image button not working inside a function

Tags: python, tk-toolkit

Here is the code:

```
img_b64 = """R0lGODlhGAAYAPEAADIyMjMzMzQ0NAAAACH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAYABgAAAJOnI8Ciu0I4gKvtmXzidoKBXbQBE5iVJZYJpGkQlluisYVnYbVgk/+XcOBBMAebWecFWfMR1Lo+DCNjuD0JcpqZUPmFSbjrbYDGJF8YGQKADs="""
img = PhotoImage(data = img_b64)
close_button = Button(root, image=img, command=root.quit)
close_button.pack(side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()

# def poptk(root):
#     img_b64 = """R0lGODlhGAAYAPEAADIyMjMzMzQ0NAAAACH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAAYABgAAAJOnI8Ciu0I4gKvtmXzidoKBXbQBE5iVJZYJpGkQlluisYVnYbVgk/+XcOBBMAebWecFWfMR1Lo+DCNjuD0JcpqZUPmFSbjrbYDGJF8YGQKADs="""
#     img = PhotoImage(data = img_b64)
#     close_button = Button(root, image=img, command=root.quit)
#     close_button.pack(side=LEFT)
# poptk(root)
# root.mainloop()
```

The first part is the working code, but once I refactor it into a function, the image then can't be displayed, and clicking has no effect.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]